# Python code compiled to a standalone program with Nuitka reports win32file.pyd import error

Tags: python, importerror, nuitka, python-standalone

Program compiled on Windows 10 amd64 machine fails to start on Windows server 2008R2 amd64 with error:

`ImportError: LoadLibraryEx 'path\to\dist\folder\win32file.pyd' failed`

Nuitka version: 0.5.29.1 stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem happened to be the same as described in this stackoverflow thread: [Problem with loading win32file.pyd on python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439621/problem-with-loading-win32file-pyd-on-python-2-6)

**Solution was to remove MSWSOCK.dll from the dist directory**